# How to get year, month and hour in Wordpress?

Tags: php, posts, date-time, formatting

Here is the code which gives me only day and month.

I want to show all: year, month, day, hour and minutes.

How can I do this?

```
print '<time class="entry-date updated" datetime="' . esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( the_date('F j, Y','G:i'))  .  '</time>';
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP Date Format in WordPress function:

You'll have to use the proper [`date format string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (as used in PHP `date` function) in the WordPress [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) function's first parameter.

For example, to get the Date & Time in the format like `2018-07-23 23:59` (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM, where hour is in 24 hour format), you need CODE like:

```
get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Or, to get the Date & Time in the format like `23-07-2018 11:59 PM` (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM AM/PM, where hour is in 12 hour format with AM or PM), you need CODE like:

```
get_the_date('d-m-Y h:i A');
```

So your full example CODE will be:

```
print '<time class="entry-date updated" datetime="' . esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'd-m-Y h:i A' ) )  .  '</time>';
```

### Mistakes in your CODE:

The ***idea*** in your CODE is not entirely wrong, only the CODE has two mistakes:

1. You've used the `the_date` function, instead of `get_the_date` function. The way you've concatenated the string, `the_date` will not work as it prints the date immediately, doesn't return as the `get_the_date` function does.
2. You've used `'F j, Y', 'G:i'` as two parameters, where as, it should be just one parameter: `'F j, Y G:i'`.

So if you correct these two mistakes, the proper CODE will be:

```
print '<time class="entry-date updated" datetime="' . esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'F j, Y G:i' ) )  .  '</time>';
```

---

### Further Reading:

There are many other possibilities and all are in the `Date Format` string as described in [PHP `date` function documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). There are some useful examples in [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) as well.

Comment: How can i do so:   01.08.2017, 12.00 Uhr

Comment: What's `Uhr`? Also, which one of `01` & `08` is month & date?

Comment: Also, please check the Date Format reference link mentioned in the answer. That way you'll be able to generate any format you want.

Comment: [This link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) has the date formatting description as well.

Comment: Fayaz,  01 is day and 08 is month. althe first day and next month

Comment: In that case the format string will be like: `get_the_date( 'd.m.Y, H.i' )`

Answer (score 1):

Change this part `the_date('F j, Y','G:i')` to `get_the_date('F j, Y G:i')`.

[WP - Formatting Date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)